# How can I have a copy of same robot in Gazebo simulation

Tags: ros

I am working on a robot using Gazebo simulator, now I want to have a copy of the same robot in Gazebo simulator. Please tell, How can I achieve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get helpful answers, please include the code or steps you have tried so far to solve this problem so we can help you debug or improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can add another robot in world using `spawn_model`, this is a demo command please write your params as given

```
rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file `rospack find MYROBOT_description`/urdf/MYROBOT.urdf -urdf -x 0 -y 0 -z 1 -model MYROBOT
```

if you need more help you can find more about `spawn_model`